# How Base class initialize when initialize Sub class

Tags: java

The code is like this :

```
class Base {
    int x = 10;

    public Base() {
        this.printMessage();
        x = 20;
    }

    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println("Base.x = " + x);
    }
}

class Sub extends Base {
    int x = 30;

    public Sub() {
        this.printMessage();
        x = 40;
    }

    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println("Sub.x = " + x);
    }
}

public class DispatchTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base b = new Sub();
        System.out.println(b.x);
    }
}
```

The result is :

```
Sub.x = 0
Sub.x = 30
20
```

Can anybody please tell me how this code run? 
Why doesn't the costructor of class Base run?

Comment: I recently posted a [Similar Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18138397/1679863)

Comment: Use a debugger, and execute the code step by step. Understand that the first thing the the Sub constructor does is to invoke the Base constructor.

Comment: constructor chaining, anti pattern, its a long answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you created a new `Sub` object instance. The class `Sub` has the `printMessage()` method overriden, which means that the `Base.printMethod()` is not being executed.

The constructor of the `Base` class runs, but the `this.printMessage()` executes the `printMessage` method from the `Sub` class.

Immediatelly after the `Sub`'s constructor has been invoked, the `Base` constructor is being called. It prints `Sub.x = 0` because no `x` (in `Sub`) has been set so far. After that the value `x` gets assigned.

After the `Base` constructor is done, the rest of the `Sub` constructor is being executed. It prints calls the `Sub`'s `printMessage` method again, but this time the value `x` has a value, and it prints `Sub.x = 30`.

The `20` comes from the `System.out.println(b.x);`.

You might wonder, why the value `x`is not assigned during the first `printMessage` call? Because you have `x` in your `Sub` class as well, so the `x` from the `Base` class is not visible!

Answer (score 1):

Your SuperClass constructor is always called but "**Polymorphic behaviour cannot be seen when accessing overridden member variables**".

```
  Base b = new Sub();
  System.out.println(b.x);
```

Now if you access x(which is present in both subclass and superclass) it is actually the type of reference variable which determines the value.

**Note:** This behaviour is different with overridden methods,in this case it is actually the type of object which determines the method to be called not the type of reference variable.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor

```
    public Sub() {
        this.printMessage();
        x = 40;
    }
```

is equivalent to

```
public Sub() {
        super();
        this.printMessage();
        x = 40;
}
```

So when you create

```
Base b = new Sub();
```

`Base`'s constructor gets executed followed by `Sub`'s constructor. [See JLS 8.8.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7), which states

> The first statement of a constructor body may be an explicit
>   invocation of another constructor of the same class or of the direct
>   superclass

---

`Base`'s constructor is calling `printMessage()` which is **overriden** by `Sub`. When it gets called from `Base`'s constructor `printMessage()` prints `x` of `Sub` which is not yet initialized. This is an anti pattern, so `Sub.x = 0` gets printed (`x` is not yet initialized, and hence default value of int which is `0` )

---

Now once the `Bas`e's constructor finishes, `Sub`'s constructor gets called and now the `x` is initialized to `30` why?

because

```
class Sub extends Base {
    int x = 30;

    public Sub() {
        this.printMessage();
        x = 40;
    }
    ....
```

essentially means

```
class Sub extends Base {
    int x;

    public Sub() {
        {
            x=30;
        }
        this.printMessage();
        x = 40;
    }
    ....
```

hence this time `printMessage()` prints `Sub.x = 30`

---

finally `20` is printed because **fields** are **NOT overriden**.

Answer (score 0):

When ever we are creating child class object then the following sequence of events will be executed automatically.

> Step 1.Identification of instance members from parent to child and initialize them to default value.

after first step

> Base instance variable is int x=0;
>   Sub instance variable is int x=0;
>
> Step 2. Execution of instance variable assignments and instance blocks  **only in parent class**

after second step

> Base class instance variable is int x= 10;
>   Sub class instance variable is int x = 0;
>
> Step 3.Execution of parent class constructor.

after third step

> here you have a "printMessage()" invocation.It is overridden in child class Sub
>   So Sub class method is executes and prints Sub class's variable x value,which is now assigned as 0 only.
>   So the out put now "Sub.x = 0".
>   and Base class int x = 20;
>   Sub class int x = 0;
>
> Step 4.Execution of instance variables and instance blocks in child class.

After 4th step

> Base class int x=20;
>   Sub class int x=30;
>
> Step 5.Execution of child constructor.

After 5th step.

> In Sub class constructor you have "printMessage()" method invocation.So it will executes and prints output.
>   So the out put now "Sub.x = 30".
>   After the method invocation you have an assignment.
>   So now Base class int x=20;
>   Sub class int x=40;

For now your Sub  class constructor created successfully.
Now you a print statement of variable x on type reference "Base".So now "Base" class variable x will be prints as output.

> So the out put is "20".