# Access function before calling superclass constructor in Kotlin data class

Tags: java, kotlin, data-class

I'm using data classes in Kotlin to significantly reduce the amount of Java code I would otherwise have to write.

However, in one of my Java classes, I'm not sure what to do to achieve the same result in Kotlin.

My Java class looks a bit like this:

```
public class DataObject {

    private int mId;
    private String mName;

    public DataObject(int id, String name) {
        mId = id;
        mName = name;
    }

    public DataObject(Context context, int id) {
        mId = id;
        Cursor cursor = ...
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        mName = cursor.getString(...);
        cursor.close();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

}
```

I've tried to rewrite it in Kotlin, and so far I have this:

```
data class DataObject(val id: Int, val name: String) {

    constructor(context: Context, id: Int) : this(id, fetchName(context))

    private fun fetchName(context: Context): String {
        val cursor = ...
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        val name = cursor.getString(...)
        cursor.close()
        return name
    }

}
```

But my IDE (Android Studio) is underlining the part where I call `fetchName(context)` in my `constructor` in red. It displays the following message:

> Cannot access `fetchName` before superclass constructor has been called

How should I resolve this issue?

Comment: Note that you don't really need `data` here

Comment: @voddan `data` as in `data class`? Why not?

Comment: your initial java class does not have `toString`or `equals`, right? So the kotlin version does actually more if you add `data`. Nothing bad about it, but something to note ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can only use member functions on a fully constructed objects. 
One way to work around that is to use private [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) or simply a function to fetch name:

```
private fun Context.fetchName(): String {
    ///...
    return cursor.getString(1)
}

data class DataObject(val id: Int, val name: String) {
    constructor(context: Context, id: Int) : this(id, context.fetchName())
}
```

Although I do think that using `Cursor` is a bit too heavy job for `constructor`. I'd use separate [`Factory`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) like so:

```
data class DataObject(val id: Int, val name: String) {
    object FromCursorFactory {
        fun create(id: Int, context: Context): DataObject {
            val name = context.fetchName()
            return DataObject(id, name)
        }
    }
}
```

Further reading:

- [Is doing a lot in constructors bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048515/is-doing-a-lot-in-constructors-bad)
- [Why is it considered bad practice to call a method from within a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348797/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-call-a-method-from-within-a-constructor)

Comment: Thanks. Just had another quick question. When I put the extension function `Context.fetchName()` in the data class, it still gave me the warning, but when I moved it outside the data class, the warning disappeared. Why is this?

Comment: When an extension function is in the class it's still a function that has access to all members of the enclosing class instance and thus requires **the instance**.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use companion object. This will allow you to call the function 
outside of the data class as well (maybe not useful in your particular case)

```
data class DataObject(val id: Int, val name: String) {

  constructor(context: Context, id: Int) : this(id, fetchName(context))

  companion object {

    fun fetchName(context: Context): String {
      val cursor = ...
      ...
      return name
    }
  }
}
```