# How to use use java 9 flow to implement observer/observable pattern for simple mvc?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

Does anyone have any code sample or ideas about how to implement this using the new publisher. subscription, subscriber classes?

In mvc, usually the observable (publisher) is subclassed to be the the model and gui's and other views implement observer.

Seems like it would be simple to implement this (mvc pattern using equivalents of observer and observable) using the new classes, but i can't quite grok it.

Answer (score 3):

The Flow interfaces were added to Java 9 mostly to facilitate aligning different reactive frameworks (RxJava, Akka Streams, Spring Reactor) and aren't really intended to implement yourself. If you're interested in reactive programming, I would focus on one of these frameworks.

There are good talks available on youtube with more details, for instance this talk on why you shouldn't try to implement them yourself: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_stAxdjx8qk

Comment: i don't want to implement them myself. i want to use them to do a simple mvc.

Comment: They are only interfaces and have no implementation, so out of the box you can't use them to do anything. You can have a look at the reactive frameworks I mentioned, but I don't think that would qualify as simple MVC :)