# How to call a private method that initializes a char array inside constructor java

Tags: java

I am working on my final project in my OOP1 class. The language is java.

I'd like to know how I invoke the following method inside my constructor:

```
public Garden (int size)    {

    garden=new char[size][size];

    this.initializeGarden(garden[][]);
}


private void intializeGarden(char [][]garden)   {

    for(int i=0;i<garden.length;i++)
        for(int j =0;j<garden.length;j++)
            garden[i][j]='-';

}
```

this.initializeGarden(garden[][]); is one of several failed attempts.
I've tried a few variations, and eclipse didn't like any of them.

Comment: Just call `this.initializeGarden(garden)`, without the brackets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I call methods in constructor in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230565/can-i-call-methods-in-constructor-in-java)

Comment: Have a look at [Why is it considered bad practice to call a method from within a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348797/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-call-a-method-from-within-a-constructor)

Comment: Is `initializeGarden` part of the class?  Also, the [][] in that function call inside of the constructor is not needed.  If you are getting any errors, could you edit your answer to include them?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Garden {
char[][] garden;

public Garden (int size)    {

    garden=new char[size][size];

    this.initializeGarden(garden);
}


private void initializeGarden(char [][]garden)   {

    for(int i=0;i<garden.length;i++)
        for(int j =0;j<garden.length;j++)
            garden[i][j]='-';

}

public void display(){
    for(int i=0;i<garden.length;i++){
        for(int j =0;j<garden.length;j++){
            System.out.print(garden[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Garden(20).display();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your private method `intializeGarden` appears to have a typo in it.

So the call would look like `intializeGarden(garden)`

Comment: Yes, I saw that after posting. Thanks :) Well, at least I was not totally out to lunch. "Hmm, this should work" Yeah it does, when you spell things right!

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
this.initializeGarden(garden[][]);
```

to

```
this.initializeGarden(garden);
```

The above code will pass the garden variable as an argument to the initializeGarden method.