# Constructor - order of execution

Tags: java

```
class Alpha
{
       String name = "Alpha";
       Alpha()
       {
           print();
       }
       void print()
       {
           System.out.println("Alpha Constructor");
       }
}
class Beta extends Alpha
{
       int i =   5;
       String name = "Beta";
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          Alpha a = new Beta();
          a.print();//Line1 executes Beta constructor
          System.out.println(a.name);//Line 2 displays Alpha instance variable
       }
       void print()
       {
           System.out.println(i);
       }
}
```

This program compiles successfully and displays the following output.

```
0
5
Alpha
```

Questions

a) I dont understand why Alpha's constructor did not get executed first.

I believe "super()" will be called implicitly by every child constructor first ...right ?.

b) If Beta's constructor is already executed then why "5" is printed ? (Second Line in Output)

The third line I kinda understand (i.e Alpha's own variable will be displayed because casting is not yet done on "a" instance variable)

Comment: Where did that `0` come from?

Comment: `0` is the output of the first run of `print` where `i` is not yet overridden. Both constructors call `print`, but at the time the `Alpha`constructor calls `print``i` is not yet initialized by the instance initializer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Alpha
{
       String name = "Alpha";
       Alpha()
       {
           print();
```

This one here actually invokes `Beta.print()`, because it `@Override`s `Alpha.print()`. Since base class constructors are called first, the `Beta` part has not yet been initialized here, thus it prints 0 since...

```
       }
       void print()
       {
           System.out.println("Alpha Constructor");
       }
}
class Beta extends Alpha
{
       int i =   5;
```

this line of code has not yet been executed. Initialization within the class body is executed after the super class constructor (`super()`) but before the constructor body of the same class.

```
       String name = "Beta";
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          Alpha a = new Beta();
          a.print();//Line1 executes Beta constructor
```

Here, it will print 5, as initialization of Beta (`a`) is finished.

```
          System.out.println(a.name);//Line 2 displays Alpha instance variable
       }
```

And this is said method actually beeing called:

```
       void print()
       {
           System.out.println(i);
       }
}
```

Init/Invocation order:

- `Object.Object()`
- `Alpha.<instance vars>`
- `Alpha.<constructor body>`

  - `Beta.print()` which overrides `Alpha.print()` (prints `Beta.i`, which is still 0 (default) )
- `Beta.<instance vars>` (Here `Beta.i` will be initialized to 5)
- `Beta.<constructor body>`
- `Beta.print()` which overrides `Alpha.print()` (prints `Beta.i`, which finally is 5, since initialization is finished)

Answer (score 5):

You are committing two "felonies" here:

1. calling an overridable method from the constructor;
2. declaring an instance variable in the subclass with the same name as the one in the superclass.

Both idioms result in surprising behavior. Specifically, 1. results in `Beta#print` being called from the `Alpha`'s constructor, which results in printing `0` because you are invoking `print` on an unititialized instance of `Beta`. And this happens precisely *because* the superconstructor runs before the subclass constructor.

In summary, calling an overridden method from the constructor results in an unwanted reversal of the order of execution: control is transferred from the superclass constructor into the subclass method.

As for your question about why `5` is printed: `a.print()`, unlike `a.name`, is a method invocation subject to dynamic dispatch. So regardless of `a`'s declared type (which is `Alpha`), the `Beta#print` method is invoked (the same happens in `Alpha`'s constructor, but before the `i` variable is initialized).

Answer (score 1):

> I dont understand why Alpha's constructor did not get executed first.

It did execute first. I don't know what made you think it didn't. Perhaps the output `0`. That is because you invoked the overridden method in constructor, which will call the method `print()` in `Beta` class. Now, since at that point of time, the variable `i` hasn't been initialized yet, it will print 0. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18138445/1679863) for more details. I've also written a [blog post](http://rjcodeblog.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/whats-wrong-with-calling-overridable-method-in-constructor-3/) on this topic.

> I believe "super()" will be called implicitly by every child constructor first ...right ?

Not always. When you chain the constructor of the same class using `this()`, `super()` won't be added. Else super class constructor will be chained.

> If Beta's constructor is already executed then why "5" is printed ?

Why wouldn't it? Beta constructor will initialize `i` with `5`. The initialization which you do at the point of declaration is moved to every constructor of your class by the compiler, after the `super()` or `this()` statement, whatever is there.

Comment: Good to see your blog for the first time....You should write about regex stuffs in your blog....

Comment: @LolCoder. Sure. As time permits, and more importantly, when I think I've something interesting to write on, will post it for sure. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

- Alpha's constructor does get executed first. If you put `System.out.println("Alpha Ctr");` in `Alpha()` method you will notice `Alpha Ctr` getting printed.
- The fact is that you've overridden `print()` method in child class `Beta`. Therefore `Beta#print()` gets executed instead of `Alpha#print()`.

If you change `Beta#print()` little bit this behavior will be more clear:

```
void print() {
    System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
}
```

This will now print:

```
null: 0
Beta: 5
Alpha
```

Here it is prints `null: 0` because variable `name & i` are uninitialized at the time of construction of parent class `Alpha`.