# Java Bubblesort Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, bubble-sort

I am trying to use the summer to practice more Java to get better by learning how to code algorithms. I have this problem where I add elements to my ArrayList but somehow the first number I add also sets the number of positions in my list which I want to avoid. I only want the 0th index to contain the number 5. I seem to not catch a clue on how to solve this.

```
public class Algorithms {

private ArrayList<Integer> numbers;

public Algorithms() {

    numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(4);
    bubblesort();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Algorithms();
}

public void bubblesort() {

    System.out.println(numbers);
    for (int a = 0; a < numbers.size();) {
        for (int b = 1; b < numbers.size();) {
            int currentNumber = numbers.get(a);
            if (currentNumber > numbers.get(b)) {

                //Collections.swap(numbers, currentNumber, numbers.get(b));

                numbers.set(numbers.get(a), numbers.get(b));
                numbers.set(numbers.get(b), numbers.get(a));

                a++;
                b++;

            } else if (currentNumber < numbers.get(b)) {
                a++;
                b++;
            }
            System.out.println(numbers);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you think `numbers.set(numbers.get(a), numbers.get(b));` should be doing? Did you take a look at the `ArrayList` API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not swapping elements correctly. Instead of

```
numbers.set(numbers.get(a), numbers.get(b));
numbers.set(numbers.get(b), numbers.get(a));
```

it should be

```
int temp = numbers.get(a);
numbers.set(a, numbers.get(b));
numbers.set(b, temp);
```

Comment: Right so that's now all working, however when I choose to add more elements to the list it sorts i, but at the expense of an  indexoutofBounds Exception I know that it's to do with the temporary variable int currentNumber = numbers.get(a); pointing to the next index of the list which doesn't exist. I can't seem to find a way how to get around that problem if you could please help me find a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

The below two statements:

```
numbers.set(numbers.get(a), numbers.get(b));
numbers.set(numbers.get(b), numbers.get(a));
```

is not performing swapping. The first argument to the [`List#set(int, E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) method is the index in the list, where you want to set the value passed as 2nd argument. You need to use a `temp` variable for swapping.

Also, the swapping didn't work for your commented line for the same reason. [`Collections#swap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List,%20int,%20int%29) method take indices for swapping. So, just change:

```
Collections.swap(numbers, currentNumber, numbers.get(b));
```

to:

```
Collections.swap(numbers, a, b);
```

---

And please for the love of all that is holy, [**don't call method from inside a constructor**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18138397/1679863). Remove the method invocation from inside the constructor, and move it to main method like this:

```
Algorithms algo = new Algorithms();
algo.bubbleSort()
```

Comment: Oh so that's the way I can call methods directly from the main method. Cheers :)