# Inheritance, super constructors, and private methods

Tags: java

Can anyone explain the output of below code?
Trying to extend class A in Class B and overriding method goo() and
method foo() is called from the constructor.

```
public class A {

    public A() {
        foo();
    }

    private void foo() { // Private function foo()
        System.out.print("A::foo ");
        goo();
    }

    public void goo() {
        System.out.print("A::goo ");
    }
}


public class B extends A {

    public B() {
        foo();
    }

    public void foo() {
        System.out.print("B::foo ");
    }

    public void goo() {
        System.out.print("B::goo ");
    }

}


public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A b = new B();
    }

}
```

Output : A::foo B::goo B::foo

Thanks.

Comment: `foo()` is not overriden.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/18138397/1679863

Answer (score 8):

First, `private` methods are not inherited. So the `foo()` in `A` is different than the `foo()` in `B`.

Second, when you call

```
A b = new B();
```

The super constructor of `B`, so `A`'s, is called implicitly so this gets executed first

```
public A() {
    foo(); // A's version
}

private void foo() { // Private function foo()
    System.out.print("A::foo ");
    goo();
}
```

`goo()` is executed polymorphically, ie. `B`'s implementation.

```
public void goo() {
    System.out.print("B::goo ");
}
```

Then the `B` constructor is executed, executing

```
public B() {
    foo(); // B's version
}

public void foo() {
    System.out.print("B::foo ");
}
```

---

Be careful when (directly or indirectly) calling methods that might be overriden from super/parent class constructors. The state of the child object might not have been initialized yet.