# java constructor execution process between base class and derived class

Tags: java

**class Base:**

```
public class Base {
    private String name = "base";

    public Base() {
        tellName();
        printName(name);
    }

    public void tellName() {
        System.out.println("Base tell name:" + name);
    }

    public void printName(String name) {
        System.out.println("Base print name:" + name);
    }
}
```

**class Derived:**

```
public class Derived extends Base {
    private String name = "Derived";

    public Derived() {
        tellName();
        printName(name);
    }

    public void tellName() {
        System.out.println("Derived tell name:" + name);
    }

    public void printName(String name) {
        System.out.println("Derived print name:" + name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Derived derived = new Derived();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Derived tell name:null
Derived print name:base
Derived tell name:Derived
Derived print name:Derived
```

Recently, I was asked this question. I thought about it, but didn't have exact answer of why this program section has such execute result.
Hope someone can help me analyze such problem. Thanks a lot! ^-^

I just want to know the execution process of constructor in derived condition.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling method from constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138397/calling-method-from-constructor)

Comment: I don't even see the question.

Comment: Although this question doesn't actually makes sense, as you haven't asked any question actually. But there is one obvious issue with the code.

Comment: My car is not fixed. Here is the old brake pedal. Thanks a lot! ^-^

Comment: I just want to know the execution process of constructor in derived condition.

Comment: I just want to fix the process of braking pedal on auto-mobile condition. Speak some sense...

Comment: You're not using the methods of the base class since you're hiding them in your derived class.

Comment: I search for `?`, found no question.

Comment: (You're getting a hard time for not asking a specific question.  In SO one should always clearly state what specific question you want answered.)

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any confusion at all. Whenever you call the constructor, it will invoke the parent class constructor. so, when you construct Derived instance, it will implicitly call Base class constructor. This will set the member variable 'name' to value 'base' in base instance. After that the methods `tellName()` and `printName()` are invoked in the base constructor, this will actually invoke the methods on the actual instance. i.e. **Derived** instance. At this point, the member variable 'name' in Derived instance is null, that's why you see `Derived tell name:null`. After that, when the method printName is invoked by passing the 'name' member variable in base instance, this is just passed to the method in Derived instance.that's why `Derived print name:base`. Once the parent constructor is completed, the member variable 'name' in Derived instance is set to value 'Derived' and then it invokes the tellName() and printName(name) on the Derived instance. so, that's why we see the next two lines of output

```
Derived tell name:Derived
Derived print name:Derived
```

That's tha long story behind!

Comment: Except that it's not a StackOverflow thing to ask for upticks/acceptance.  You actually risk getting downticked.

Comment: (And it should be pointed out that you should not depend on the order of instance initializations.  Some are performed out of the constant table and occur early, others are melded into the constructor and occur later -- it's up to the compiler and the particular data type.)

Comment: Thank you very much, Keerthi Ramanathan,I was just wondering the sentence you write, such as "this will actually invoke the methods on the actual instance. i.e. Derived instance.".What was trouble me is that how does dynamic dispatch in constructor of superclass works.Does reference of Derived Class transfer to superclass?Looking for your reply,Thank you.^-^

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for the information about constant table. +1

Answer (score 0):

Execution starts in `Derived.main`. This creates a new instance of `Derived`, so the `Derived` constructor is invoked. This starts by invoking the `Base` constructor, which initialises the `Base` sub-object's `name` and then makes a call to `tellName`. Due to dynamic dispatch, the `tellName` that is called is `Derived.tellName` and not `Base.tellName`. The text this prints refers to the `Derived` sub-object's `name`, which has not yet been initialised, rather than the `Base` sub-object's `name`, which has been initialised, hence `"Derived tell name:null"` is printed. Control resumes in the `Base` constructor, which next calls `printName` with the `Base` sub-object's `name`. Due to dynamic dispatch, `Derived.printName` is invoked. The `name` it prints is its argument, which (as we just saw) is the `name` from the `Base` sub-object. Hence it prints `"Derived print name:base"`, since the `Base` sub-object's `name` has previously been initialised to `"base"`. The `Base` constructor has now completed, and control resumes in the `Derived` constructor. This now initialises the `Derived` sub-object's `name` to `"Derived"` and then calls `Derived.tellName` and `Derived.printName` in the obvious way, with the observed results.

As an extra observation, it's worth noting that the issue here arises because Java dynamically dispatches virtual calls in constructors; other languages such as C++ don't, e.g. see:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/calling-virtuals-from-ctors.html