# calling an overriden method inside a constructor of both the parent and sub classes

Tags: java, polymorphism

i got a question in my Java test and i was wrong. please explain to me why.

```
public class A {
    protected String str = "A";
    public static int i = 1;
    public A() {
        foo();
    }
    public void foo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(str + " " + i);
    }
}
public class B extends A {
    protected String str = "B";
    public static int i = 2;
    public B() {
        foo();
    }
    public void foo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(str + " " + i);

    }
}
public class Program {
    public static void main(String args[]){

                A a = new B();
                B b = new B();
    }
}
```

in the test they asked me what is the output?
i answered : "A 1 B 2 A 1 B 2"
but the correct answer was : "null 2 B 2 null 2 B 2"
could you please explain why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178133/polymorphism-inside-constructors-in-java

Comment: Terrible title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the line `A a = new B();` the output is `null 2 B 2`, because the instance fields in your class are not initialized until the implicit `super()` is finished running.

In this case since `class B` is extending the `class A` the `B()` constructor will implicitly call the super class no-arg constructor `A()` through `super()`, where the `foo()` method is called.

```
public A() {                                            <---
    foo(); //overriden version in class B is called        |
}                                                          |
                                                           |
public B() {                                               |
    // Static fields are already initialized               |
    // Instance fields are not yet initialized             |
    // Here super() is called implicitly which calls A() ---
    // Instance fields are now initialized to respective values
    foo();
}
```

The overriden `foo()` of `class B` is called and as the `foo()` is overriden in `class B`, now since the `super()` is not yet finished the instance fields of `class B` is not initialized and is `null`. So you see the first `null 2`.

Then when the control comes out of `super()` the instance initializers are run for `B` and then `foo()` of `class B` is called at which point the instance fields of `class B` is initialized to the value `B`, so you see `B 2` printed.

You don't see any issue for the static fields as because they don't depend on the `super()` call to finish, they are initialized when the class is loaded, so you see the value of `i` always initialized and printed instead of `null`.

Same is the case for the line `B b = new B();`.

An important thing to note is that you have redefined the `str` instance field in class `B`, so when the overriden `foo()` is invoked it will actually refer to the instance field of the class `B` rather than the field of class `A`.

Consider this code, where I removed the `str` field from class `B`:

```
class A {
    protected String str = "A";
    public static int i = 1;
    public A() {
        foo();
    }
    public void foo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(str + " " + i);
    }
}
 class B extends A {
    public static int i = 2;
    public B() {
        foo();
    }
    public void foo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(str + " " + i);

    }
}
```

This will print the output below when you re-run your program:

```
A 2
A 2
A 2
A 2
```

This is happening because the `super()` of `B` is calling the constructor `A()` which in turn is calling the `Object()` constructor through its own `super()`. Once the `super()` is done in `A()` the instance members of `B` inherited from `A` are all initialised. Now the overriden `foo()` will print out the initialised value of `str` inherited from `A`.

Answer (score 0):

`new B()` will attempt to create a new instance of B, using B's constructor. All constructors always start with a `super()` call even if said call isn't there. Separate from that there are the 'instance initializers'; these are the expressions being assigned to the `str` variable. They are not string constants because that'd require a static final variable and `str` isn't.

Methods overload, but fields do not: Each class has its own field named `str` unrelated to the other one's `str` field.

The order of execution for object creation is as follows:

1. First, set all fields to initial value (null / 0 / false)
2. Run the super() call from the targeted constructor in B to figure out which constructor is intended for A(), along with the parameters required to call the constructor of the parent.
3. Invoke that superconstructor (which itself does this 5-step routine on its own stuff too!)
4. run all instance initializers in this class.
5. now continue and run the rest of the constructor.

So, in order:

1. `A.str`, `B.str` are both set to null.
2. `A.str = "A"` is evaluated.
3. A's constructor runs, and calls `foo()`. foo is a method, so dynamic dispatch is used; B overrides it, this is an instance of B, therefore, run B's foo(), not A's foo().
4. B's foo runs, and prints B's `str` which is still null.
5. B's foo prints its version of 'i', which is 2. Hence `null 2`
6. Now `B.str = "B"` is evaluated.
7. now the rest of B's constructor is run, which again runs B's foo(), but this time `B.str` has been initialized, so it prints `B 2` instead.
8. Then we do it again; the type of the variable you assign the instance to has absolutely no effect here, so, `null 2 B 2` prints a second time.