# How to make abstract class more concise?

Tags: java

I have a abstract class about crawler:

```
public abstract class AbstractCrawler {
    public AbstractCrawler(){
        initialize();
    }
    protected abstract void initialize();
    protected abstract void work();
    protected abstract void saveAndUpdate(Object obj);
}
```

As you can see,abstract method of "saveAndUpdate" needs the param of Object,Because,each crawler extends this abstract will save or update different data type,like this:

```
public class UserCrawler extends AbstractCrawler{
    @Override
    protected void saveAndUpdate(List<User> obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

and class of CommentCrawler:

```
public class CommentCrawler extends AbstractCrawler{
        @Override
        protected void saveAndUpdate(List<Comment> obj) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
}
```

It's pretty obvious, just do something like this.Making abstract class more concise.

Comment: Use generics `public abstract class AbstractCrawle<T> {` and then `protected abstract void saveAndUpdate(T obj)`....

Comment: [Be careful.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138397/calling-method-from-constructor)

Comment: @MadProgrammer But oher programmers don't know what T is,they just want to use the function of class by public method.how about Use Object and doing converte in the subclass method of "saveAndUpdate".

Comment: That's the point `T` is generic, in order to work with it, they need to define it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the inbuilt generics support, for example...

```
public abstract class AbstractCrawler<T> {
    public AbstractCrawler(){
        initialize();
    }
    protected abstract void initialize();
    protected abstract void work();
    protected abstract void saveAndUpdate(T obj);
}
```

This allows implementations to specify the type of data they are expecting to work with...

```
public class CommentCrawler extends AbstractCrawler<List<Comment>> {
    @Override
    protected void saveAndUpdate(List<Comment> obj) {
        //....
    }

    //...
}
```

Also, be careful calling methods from constructors, what the method might rely on might not have yet been initialized.

Have a look at [Lesson: Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for more details...